# Cubic Hermite Spline behaving strangely

Tags: c#, graphing, spline

I'm attempting to draw a graph using [Cubic Hermite Splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline). I grabbed the simple code to do so from this [interpolation methods](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) page.

Here is my code:

```
private float HermiteInterpolate(float y0, float y1, float y2, float y3, float mu)
{
    var mu2 = mu * mu;

    var a0 = -0.5f * y0 + 1.5f * y1 - 1.5f * y2 + 0.5f * y3;
    var a1 = y0 - 2.5f * y1 + 2f * y2 - 0.5f * y3;
    var a2 = -0.5f * y0 + 0.5f * y2;
    var a3 = y1;

    return (a0 * mu * mu2) + (a1 * mu2) + (a2 * mu) + a3;
}
```

With this data (y-values, from 0-1, x-values are distributed evenly from 0-21):

`0, 0.09448819, 0.1102362, 0.1338583, 0.1811024, 0.2283465 ,0.3543307, 0.4645669, 0.480315, 0.480315, 0.527559, 0.527559, 0.527559, 0.527559, 0.527559, 0.527559, 0.6062992, 0.6377953, 0.6377953, 0.6377953, 0.7480315`

And here is the result:

[image: Hermite Graph]

The problem is, at some areas of the graph, the line goes *downward*. Looking at the data, it never decreases. I don't know if the algorithm is supposed to do this, but for what I am working on, I want the lines to never go downward (and if I was drawing the graph by hand, I would never make them point downward anyway).

So,

- Is there something wrong with the graphing?
- Is the algorithm supposed to do this? If so, is there one where this doesn't happen?
- I have tried cosine interpolation, but didn't like how it turned out.

Here is the actual graphing function:

```
public void DrawGraph(IList<float> items)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < Width; x++)
    {
        var percentThrough = (float)x / (float)Width;
        var itemIndexRaw = items.Count * percentThrough;
        var itemIndex = (int)Math.Floor(itemIndexRaw);

        var item = items[itemIndex];
        var previousItem = (itemIndex - 1) < 0 ? item : items[itemIndex - 1];
        var nextItem = (itemIndex + 1) >= items.Count ? item : items[itemIndex + 1];
        var nextNextItem = (itemIndex + 2) >= items.Count ? nextItem : items[itemIndex + 2];

        var itemMu = FractionalPart(itemIndexRaw);

        var pointValue = HermiteInterpolate(previousItem, item, nextItem, nextNextItem, itemMu);

        WritePixel(x, (int)(pointValue * Height) - 1, (1 - FractionalPart(pointValue)), false);
        WritePixel(x, (int)(pointValue * Height), 1.0f, false);
        WritePixel(x, (int)(pointValue * Height) + 1, FractionalPart(pointValue), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Snea, I am trying to understand how Cubic Hermite Spline works.  Could you please tell me how you call your HermiteInterpolate method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behavior is normal.

Interpolation methods impose certain continuity conditions in order to give the appearance of a smooth curve. For Hermite interpolation, there is no condition that the interpolating curve through a sequence of increasing values must also be increasing everywhere, and so sometimes you get the effect you show here.

There is something called [monotone cubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) which does what you want: if the data points are increasing, the interpolating curve will be increasing everywhere also.

Comment: Excellent! Now I just have to figure out to interpret all those steps as code.